# How to watch ng-model included in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

This is my html code:

```
<table>
            <tr ng-repeat="park in parkOptions.parks">
                <td>
                    <label for="{{park.park_id}}">
                        <input id="{{park.park_id}}" type="radio" name="connection" ng-model="$parent.currentPark" value="{{park.park_id}}" ng-click="selectValue('park',park)"/>{{park.park_name}}
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

How can i watch the changes in my model( I mean i want to see in $watch another park when i click radio button)

Comment: $scope.$watch("currentPark", function(newValue, oldValue) {}); ?

Comment: No, I suppose. If i print newValue i get all the values

Answer (score 1):

I've got a working version to help you - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5vskLfc/28/).

HTML

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="park in parkOptions.parks">
                <td>
                    <label for="{{park.park_id}}">
                        <input id="{{park.park_id}}" type="radio" name="connection" ng-model="parkOptions.currentPark" value="{{park.park_id}}" ng-click="selectValue(park)"/> {{park.park_name}}
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function ParentCtrl($scope) {
}

function ChildCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.parkOptions = {};
    $scope.parkOptions.parks = [
        {park_id: '01', park_name: 'England Park'},
        {park_id: '02', park_name: 'France Park'}
    ];
    $scope.$watch('parkOptions.currentPark', function(newValue) {
        if (newValue != undefined) {
            console.log(newValue);
        }
    });
}
```

This may not be exactly what you want (as I see $parent in your code) but we can come to the right solution with any further information from you.

I don't use $parent and prefer sending and receiving events.